# How to activate an installed plugin (NetworkAnalyzer) on Cytoscape?

Tags: cytoscape

I need to use NetworkAnalyzer to analyse the nodes of a PPI network on Cytoscape, but the pre-installed app is not displayed on the Tools menu.

I checked the App Manager, but it shows "Installed" beside the app name and also it is not in the Currently installed apps list, which is why I'm unable to perform uninstall-reinstall to fix it.

I've once replaced the app by installing it manually, but despite of that there's no change in the Tools menu.

There's an option "Analyse Network" in the Tools, probably a substitute of NetworkAnalyzer, but it is not showing the usual attributes (Degree, BetweenessCentrality etc) which are displayed on using Network Analyzer app.

[image]